# How many times do we write '1' if all the numbers from 1 to 64 are in base 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**My attempt:-**

Listing down all numbers from $(1)_2$ to $(1000000)_2$

$1->1$ ; $Total = 1$

$10-> 1$, $11-> 2$ ; $Total = 1+2$

$100-> 1$, $101-> 2$, $110-> 2$, $111-> 3$ ; $Total = 1+2+2+3$

$1000-> 1$, $1001-> 2$, $1010-> 2$, $1011-> 3$, $1110-> 3$, $1111-> 4$ ; $Total = 1+2+2+3+3+4$

Following the pattern for 5 digit, 6 digit numbers $(1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5)$ and $(1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5+5+6)$ respectively

And finally the 7 digit number will have just one time '1' used

Therefore the answer should be adding all these above numbers up, however my answer is not matching with the one given in the textbook.

---

Please also suggest if there is any other efficient solution

Comment: Just do it from $0$ to $63$ first (note:  adding the $0$ doesn't change the count).  There are $64$ numbers in that range and each entry is $1$ in exactly half of them (why?).  That makes it easy to read off the answer.

Comment: Should say:  I can't follow what you wrote.  What are you saying your final result is?

Comment: Re the comment of @lulu, instead of looking at the individual numbers, look at the individual columns.  Further, you can (harmlessly) zero-fill on the left, so that each number has exactly $~6~$ digits (i.e. 6 columns of digits).  Then, in each column, (1/2) of the numbers are 1's.  To this overall computation, you have to add 1, because (at the end), you must distinguish between the base-2 representations of 64 and 0.

Comment: Alternative analysis is that in the base 2 representations of $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,63\},~$ you can form $~32~$ pairs of form $~(k,63-k)~$ where the two pairs will be **one-s complements** of each other.  That is, $~k~$ will have a $~1~$ in digit place $~n ~: ~n \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}~$ if and only if $~63-k~$ has a $~0~$ in that digit place.  This holds because for each such $~k,~$ you have that $~k + (63-k) = 63.$

Comment: @lulu my final result is the addition of all the totals = $1+(1+2)+(1+2+2+3)+(1+2+2+3+3+4)+(1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5)+(1+2+2+3+3+4+4+5+5+6)+1 = 87$ 1's

Comment: So, do it for a smaller cap and see how your method plays out. Try a cap of $8$ or $16$ in place of $64$.  It is always good to work explicit examples.

Comment: @lulu it is working for 8 , see as per the pattern it should be 1+(1+2)+(1+2+2+3)+1, which is matching the answer when I list the numbers 1,10,11,100,101,110,111 and finally 1000

Comment: You are missing $1100$ and $1101$ for your 4-digit case.

Comment: Oh yes @DanielMathias thank you I missed that , hopefully the answer should match now

Comment: @user2661923 can you write an answer please of what you meant by the column thing , I am not able to understand that

Comment: Note: there are 16 5-digit numbers and 32 6-digit numbers.

Comment: @Fin27 Answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer given per the request of the OP (i.e. original poster).

Restrict attention to the numbers $~0~$ through $~63.~$  Then, at the end, because the original problem instead specified the numbers $~1~$ through $~64,~$ you simply add +1 to the computation re the set $\{0,1,2,\cdots,63\}.$

This is because in base 2, you have that $~0~$ and $~64~$ are expressed as $~0~$ and $~1000000~$ respectively.

---

Left zero fill each of the numbers in the set $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,63\}.$  This zero filling is harmless because you are being asked to compute the number of occurrences of the digit 1.

So, you will now have a *tableau* of 64 numbers, that in base 2 look as follows:

```
000000
000001
000010
000011
000100
......
111110
111111
```

The problem is then solved by realizing that of the $~(6 \times 64)~$ digits shown in the above tableau, exactly $~(1/2)~$ of them are 1's.

So, the overall answer to the original question is

$$\frac{6 \times 64}{2} + 1.$$

So, the entire problem reduces to showing that exactly $~(1/2)~$ of the numbers in the tableau are 1's.

The remainder of this response provides two separate methods of showing that $~(1/2)~$ of the numbers in the tableau are 1's.

---

$\underline{\text{Method 1}}$

Examine the tableau column by column.  It turns out that in each column, of the 64 digits in that column, exactly (1/2) of them are 1's.  To see this, you have to analyze the pattern of 1's and 0's in each column.  Start with the leftmost column, which corresponds to the $~2^5~$ placeholder in the base 2 representation of the numbers.

For the $~32~$ numbers between $~0~$ and $~31~$ inclusive, the digit in the leftmost column will be $~0.~$ For the $~32~$ numbers $~\geq 2^5 = 32,~$ the digit will be $~1.$

Now, focus on the 2nd column from the left, which corresponds to the $~2^4~$ placeholder.

For the $~16~$ numbers between $~0~$ and $~15~$ inclusive, the digit in this column will be $~0.~$ For the $~16~$ numbers between $~2^4 = 16,~$ and $~31,~$ inclusive, the digit will be $~1.$  Then, for the numbers between $~32~$ and $~63~$ inclusive, the exact same pattern will repeat.

Now, focus on the 3nd column from the left, which corresponds to the $~2^3~$ placeholder.

For the $~8~$ numbers between $~0~$ and $~7~$ inclusive, the digit in this column will be $~0.~$ For the $~8~$ numbers between $~2^3 = 8,~$ and $~15,~$ inclusive, the digit will be $~1.$  Then, for the numbers between $~16~$ and $~63~$ inclusive, the exact same pattern will repeat three times.

You will then see analagous repeated patterns in each of the other $~3~$ columns.  So, in each column, exactly $~(1/2)~$ of the digits will be 1's.

---

$\underline{\text{Method 2}}$

The $~64~$ numbers in the set $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,63\}~$ can be used to create exactly $~32~$ pairs of numbers of the form
$~(k, ~63 - k) ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,31\}.~$

Consider the base 2 representation of the two numbers in any one of these pairs:

```
  k      : d-5 d-4 d-3 d-2 d-1 d-0
+ 63 - k : e-5 e-4 e-3 e-2 e-1 e-0
-------- : -----------------------
  63     :   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

In the addition problem above, the RHS represents the base 2 representations of $~k, ~63-k,~$ and $~63,~$ respectively.

The base 2 representation of $~63~$ is uniquely defined to be 111111.

You can see that the only way that (for example) d-0 and e-0 can sum to 1 is if one of d-0,e-0 is 1, and the other is 0.

Further, this applies to each of the sums d-k + e-k, for each $~k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$

So, you have that the base 2 representations of $~k~$ and $~(63-k)~$ must be **one-s complements** of each other, where for each pair of digits d-k and e-k, exactly one of them is a 1.

So, for each pair of two numbers $~(k, ~63 - k),~ (1/2)~$ of the digits will be 1.  So, because the entire tableau of numbers can be used to create $~32~$ such pairs, exactly $~(1/2)~$ of the digits in the entire tableau will be 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution hinted at in comments. Including zero, there are 64 numbers arranged in 32 pairs:

$$0=000000_2\to0;\quad63=111111_2\to6;\quad0+6=6\\
1=000001_2\to1;\quad62=111110_2\to5;\quad1+5=6\\
2=000010_2\to1;\quad61=111101_2\to5;\quad1+5=6\\
3=000011_2\to2;\quad60=111100_2\to4;\quad2+4=6\\
\vdots\\
29=011101_2\to4;\quad34=100010_2\to2;\quad4+2=6\\
30=011110_2\to4;\quad33=100001_2\to2;\quad4+2=6\\
31=011111_2\to5;\quad32=100000_2\to1;\quad5+1=6$$

Calculate the total of those, and add $1$ for $64=1000000_2$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer :), I have few questions :- Why are we including 0 firstly as a case? and how does this way of recording information in pairs help us as we still are adding all one's from the numbers individually ? Or am I missing something , please guide

Comment: @Fin27 Every pair of numbers here has a total of six ones, and there are 32 pairs. That allows us to use multiplication instead of adding up or counting the ones individually. We include $0$ as the compliment of $63$.